# Add column and then insert value in the same script without parser complaining

Tags: sql-server, alter

What I want to do is add a value to a column. Now it might be that the column does not yet exist.

So what I do is check if that column exists and if not I'm adding it and then insert the value.

```
IF COL_LENGTH('version', 'minor') = NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE version ADD minor INT null;
END
GO

UPDATE version SET minor= 4;
```

The problem is that the parser complains about this as the column `minor` does not exist at parse time.

Is there a way to make this pass in a single script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use either:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO 
IF COL_LENGTH('version', 'minor') = NULL
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [version] ADD minor INT null;
END
GO

UPDATE [version] SET minor= 4;
```

OR

```
IF COL_LENGTH('version', 'minor') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE [version] ADD minor INT null;
    END
    GO

    UPDATE [version] SET minor= 4;
```

You are trying to compare `NULL = NULL`, with `ANSI_NULLS ON`

Raj

Comment: ANSI_NULLS! Excellent. The `=` was the key!